# ASP.NET MVC Bulk Data Update with viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to bulk update. I want to use viewmodel pattern. I read [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhaskarghosh/archive/2009/06/18/7128803.aspx)
and create program. Program show Database value and html looks ok. But After submit, Controller couldn't get values. Every values are 'Nothing' please point me where I missunderstanding. Thanks

```
Public Class users

    Public id As String
    Public username As String

End Class
```

ViewModel

```
Public Class UserViewModel
    Public userlist As List(Of users)
End Class
```

View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of PartnerRotation.Repositories.UserViewModel)" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<%  Html.BeginForm()%>
    <input type="submit" name="input" value="Save" />
   <table>
   <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
    <% Dim i As Integer = 0 %>
    <% For Each item In Model.userlist%>
    <tr><td> <%: Model.userlist(i).id%>
             <%: Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) Model.userlist(i).id)%>
    </td><td>
             <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.userlist(i).username)%>
    </td></tr>
 <% i = i + 1%>
 <% Next%>
  </table>
<%  Html.EndForm()%>

</asp:Content>
```

Controller -Get

```
    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim viewmodel As New UserViewModel With {
        .userlist = (From u In _db.users Select New user With {
                        .id = u.id, _
                        .username = u.username}).ToList}

        Return View(viewmodel)

    End Function
```

Controller -Post

```
    <HttpPost()> _
    Function index(ByVal userlist As IList(Of user)) As ActionResult

        For Each user In userlist

            Dim id = user.id
            Dim u = (From a In _db.PSC_MST _
                Where a.id = id).FirstOrDefault

            _db.ApplyCurrentValues(u.EntityKey.EntitySetName, user)
            _db.SaveChanges()

        Next
        Return View()

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx) instead of fields in your model classes, so that the default model binder could set them:

```
Public Class users
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property username As String
End Class

Public Class UserViewModel
    Public Property Userlist As List(Of users)
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Darin!! Now It works fine. I spent almost one-day on this. again thanks!